# How can I import tensorflow without getting an Error Message?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have successfully installed Tensorflow 2.1.0 CPU-Version (tensorflow-2.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl) on Windows 10 via pip3. However when I try to import it in Python 3.6.0, I get the following error:

```
import tensorflow
2020-05-02 20:17:07.633591: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-05-02 20:17:07.638884: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ananas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\ananas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\ananas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\ananas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\ananas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\ananas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\ananas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\ananas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I have done some research how to fix it and found that the problem may be that I haven't installed Visual Studio C++, but I have. When I try to install tensorflow-cpu or another version of tensorflow I still get an DLL Import Error, only a slightly different Traceback.

Comment: `cudart64_101.dll not found` - did you install CUDA?

Comment: I don't have a NVIDIA GPU so I can't install CUDA. Therefore I installed the CPU Version.

Comment: Run `pip uninstall -y tensorflow` first, then `pip install tensorflow-cpu`.

Comment: When I unintsall tensorflow and reinstall the CPU-Version I still get the Error.